# Destroyed my drivers after using my Ubuntu drive in Hyper-V (need to restore all device drivers)

Tags: drivers, devices, reinstall

Yeah I know really stupid.

I suspected booting my Ubuntu 18.04 drive inside a Hyper-V VM might add some additional drivers but I didn't suspect it would remove any.

Now that I have removed the drive from Hyper-V and placed it back into my laptop I can boot but I have no mouse, wifi or audio.  Somehow the nvidia driver managed to survive!

lsusb shows I have no usb devices at all!

How do I go about restoring all my device drivers?

Comment: I have found that all my USB directories in /sys/bus/usb or /dev/bus/usb do not exist!  And subsequently no usb under /proc.  Does anyone know how I recreate them.

Answer (score 0):

Problem turned out to be a custom AZURE kernel that grub was defaulting to when booting.

Redirecting grub to use my usual generic kernel fixed everything!

Comment: Can you share how that happened? I'm messing around with Hyper-V over Virtualbox for its purported performance (it's quite shit) and I don't want to mess anything up. Windows wackiness never fails to surprise.